# Http service redirect on error

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing, angular2-services

Is there any way to create an http interceptor with Angular 2 will allow you to redirect to certain routes depending on error? For example go to the /not-found route when the service responds with a 404 and to the /unauthorised route when it responds with a 401/403.

I've attempted to inject the Router into my service and use that on the error handling method but it just throws this error

`Unhandled Promise rejection: Provider parse errors: Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency!`

I've previously been able to do it with AngularJS like so:

```
function authInterceptor ($q, $injector) {
  return {
    request: function (request) {
      return request;
    },
    requestError: function (request) {
      return $q.reject(request);
    },
    response: function (response) {
      return response;
    },
    responseError: function (response) {
      if (response.status === 401 || response.status === 403) {
        $injector.get('$state').go('unauthorised');
      } else if (response.status === 404) {
        $injector.get('$state').go('notFound');
      }

      return $q.reject(response);
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extend HTTP module and intercept requests and responses.
I wrote a [gist](https://gist.github.com/mrgoos/45ab013c2c044691b82d250a7df71e4c) to demonstrate it.